# add file icon to datagrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, bitmap

I'm trying to put some File objects into a DataGrid, but I can't find a way to display the File.icon in there.

So far I have this: (ms[x] is a File)

```
listData.addItem({
    filename:ms[x].nativePath.replace(/.*\\/,""),
    path:ms[x].nativePath.replace(/\\[^\\]*$/,"\\"),
    icon:ms[x].icon.bitmaps[0]
});
```

and

```
<mx:DataGrid x="358" y="0" width="429" height="378" dataProvider="{listData}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="filename"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="icon">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:Image width="32" height="32" source="{data}">
                    </mx:Image>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" dataField="path"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

filename and path are displayed correctly, I just can't get the file icon to show.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The source of the image needs to be the path to the file and right now your sending it the whole data object.  Assuming `data.path` contains the full path including the filename you would type:

```
 <mx:Image width="32" height="32" source="{data.path}">
```

Comment: thats the thing... File.icon is not a filename, its an Icon object containing .bitmaps array. these are not real files on filesystem, so I need to display the bitmap, not an actual image file.